# How to get all transactions and also a notification on new transactions using web3 python?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py

I'm trying to work on small project related to small crypto exchange
I'm running geth on a server and using python as a programing language to communicate with geth using web3 library
What i want to do is:

1/ I want a way to get all transaction of a specific address
From what I've seen they are saying that I have to go through all the blocks in the eth blockchain , but imagine if **I have 1 million address** do I have to loop all the blocks for all 1 million address? that would be insane.

2/ I want the node to notify me whenever there's a new transaction for a specific address
In bitcoin there's an option called walletnotify that runs a script whenever you get new transaction
When I did the research on eth I only found this solution

**[How to listen for Ethereum events using Web3.py in Python](https://cryptomarketpool.com/how-to-listen-for-ethereum-events-using-web3-in-python/)**

But this is so bad because you are running a loop that execute each **second** or maybe **10** seconds or so, for just one address
If I have like **1 million address** what will I do?
Is there a way to solve these two problems?
How other exchanges do that?

Comment: [Here is an example notebook for Uniswap v3](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/uniswap-v3-price-analysis.html). You can study the source code and build your own system.

Comment: [Another example that reads events for any address](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/scripts/read-uniswap-v2-pairs-and-swaps.py).

Comment: How about getting all transactions for a specific address without need to go through all blocks?